# Verb - Using the verb Playing in context - Question

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

Overwatch league is an event based off the game overwatch, I knew what Overwatch was but not the event.

So my friend said to me:

"They're playing Overwatch league at the laundry mat" (In a surprised tone)

I didn't understand and I assumed they were playing the game at the laundry mat, when they were just playing it on the TV. 
I just need to know if that was the grammatically correct way to say the sentence. He missed the context that they were playing on the TV.

What would be the correct way to say it?

Answer (score 1):

"Playing" can mean playing a game, or playing (displaying) a TV program (as well as other meanings. This caused confusion. This could have been avoided by saying:

> They are showing  Overwatch League on the TV at the laundromat.

(By the way, it is "laundromat" not "laundry mat")

Comment: @ BobHarry The version in the question is not grammatically incorrect, it is just potentially unclear.(aside from the error of "laundry mat" but in speech this would be fine)